# MySQL Dump and Restore Single Column

Tags: mysql

I need to update some field in some table in some database from some other table in another database. Can I do a dump and restore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both databases can be accessed by the same user you can just use `UPDATE` to do the trick:

```
UPDATE target_schema.target_table tt
JOIN source_schema.source_table ss ON tt.t_id = ss.s_id
SET tt.target_column = ss.source_column;
```

Otherwise, you can restore the source table under a new name in the target schema and use the same approach.